# Error: The process '/usr/local/bin/npx' failed with exit code 1

Tags: firebase, github, deployment, workflow

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR8Ep.png)

Hallo, I got the following message from Github while deploying to firebase :

Run failed: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge - master (bb2f1f1)

build_and_deploy

npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

---

```
"status": "error",
"error": "Directory 'dist/Ghomala' for Hosting does not exist."
```

---

---

```
"status": "error",
"error": "Directory 'dist/Ghomala' for Hosting does not exist."
```

---

The process '/usr/local/bin/npx' failed with exit code 1
Retrying deploy with the --debug flag for better error output

i  hosting[lanye-ghomala]: beginning deploy...

Error: Directory 'dist/Ghomala' for Hosting does not exist.

The process '/usr/local/bin/npx' failed with exit code 1
Error: The process '/usr/local/bin/npx' failed with exit code 1

---

```
conclusion: 'failure',
output: ***
  title: 'Deploy preview failed',
  summary: "Error: The process '/usr/local/bin/npx' failed with exit code 1"
***
```

---

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.